# Set default values for a multiselect ui-component

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, uicomponent, default-values

I have a custom entity in my magento 2 install.
And one of the fields in this entity is of type multiselect and contains the list of all countries.
I'm using the ui-components for my admin form.
Since there are about 200 records in the select, I don't want to have a multiselect field because it's not that easy to use.
So I created one of those fancy multiselects similar to the categories field in the add/edit product admin section.
It looks nicer, but I cannot set a default value to it.
Here is my configuration (notice the `default` config item):

```
<field name="affected_countries" formElement="select" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select" sortOrder="100">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">RO,MD</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Affected Countries</label>
        <dataScope>affected_countries</dataScope>
        <componentType>field</componentType>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country"/>
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

It results into this:  [image]

And I'm expecting the 2 values I placed in the default field to be selected:

[image]

If I turn the element into a simple multiselect it works nicely.

```
<field name="affected_countries" formElement="multiselect" sortOrder="100">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">article</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="string">RO,MD</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Affected Countries</label>
        <dataScope>affected_countries</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <multiselect>
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country"/>
            </settings>
        </multiselect>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

[image]

I tied with this format for the `default` setting

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">RO,MD</item>
```

and this one also:

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="MD" xsi:type="string">MD</item>
    <item name="RO" xsi:type="string">RO</item>
</item>
```

Also tried with the tag `select` and `multiselect` inside the `formElements` tag.
All of my tries ended up in failure.

Using the `default` setting in any other types of fields, as [instructed here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/207727/146) (text, select, date, ...) works nicely.

Any suggestion for the fancy selects? Something I missed?

Note: I know I can supply a default value in the data provider that populates the form, but I'm trying to avoid this as it looks ugly and it's not that extensible and not consistent with the rest of the fields.

Comment: did you try with the id of the options?

Comment: MD and RO are the ids of the options. Like I said, it works with a normal multiselect using the same default values

Comment: <items name="default" xsi:type="array"> </items>

Comment: @IdhamChoudry I already tried that. It says so in the question.

Comment: @Marius, Can you guide me how can i display my custom array in multiselect having almost same situation like yours, You displayed country list but i have my custom array to display in Multiselect . I've created block for that and call it under ui_component but not working.

Comment: @LazyCoder take a look in my question at this `<options class="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Locale\Country"/>`. You need a similar class that implements `\Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface` and has a method called `toOptionArray` that returns an array with your values. each element from the array must look like this `['value' => ..., 'label' => ...]`

Comment: @Marius, Yes, I've checked that, But Actually i am looking to display product attributes there,.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220855/magento-2-how-to-display-product-attributes-value-to-custom-field-at-sales-rul
It would be great if you can guide me.

Comment: @Marius, What code did you write to save this fancy multiselect's value to DB ? I can see its not saving without writing any custom code.

Comment: Just converting from array to string. Nothing fancy for saving

Comment: Is it still not solved?

Comment: not working on 2.2.5 either.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for custom categories but in this method you have to provide countries data via database, take idea from this code and you may provide data from Db or Static Data by extending magento data, Hope it may helps

The xml code

```
    <field name="country_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\CountriesTree</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="index=create_category:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>
                <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

The Cofig Code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

class CountriesTree implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

protected $_countryCollectionFactory;

protected $_options;

protected $_childs;


public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory 
 $countryCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
}

public function toOptionArray()
{
    if ($this->_options === null) {
        $this->_options = $this->_getOptions();
    }
    return $this->_options;
}

protected function _getOptions($itemId = 0)
{
    $childs =  $this->_getChilds();
    $options = [];

    if (isset($childs[$itemId])) {
        foreach ($childs[$itemId] as $item) {
            $data = [
                'label' => $item->getCountry_title(),
                'value' => $item->getCountry_id(),
            ];

             if (isset($childs[$item->getCountry_id()])) {
                 $data['optgroup'] = $this->_getOptions($item->getCountry_id());
             }

            $options[] = $data;
        }
    }

    return $options;
}

protected function _getChilds()
{
    if ($this->_childs === null) {
        $this->_childs =  $this->_countryCollectionFactory->create()
            ->getGroupedChilds();
    }
    return $this->_childs;
}
}
```

The output looks like this 
[image]

Comment: oh...but this question was asked 7 months ago :(

Comment: The values come from the db already. I just need on the "Add screen" when I'm not editing something stored in the db to pre select default values. I don't think this solves my problem. Also, I don't need a tree-like structure. I just have a flat list of countries.

Comment: Yes we must use default data for this, in my case i write dataprovider but in your case this in not efficient approach, in your case via xml is suitable