# Magento 2 : How to display product attributes value to custom field at Sales Rule?

Tags: product-attribute, uicomponent, magento2.2.3

I am trying to display Product Custom Attribute values to **Sales Rule**.

I've created **multiselect** field using ui_component.

> vendor/module/view/adminhtml/sales_rule_form.xml

```
<field name="brand_ids" formElement="multiselect">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-brands" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <dataType>number</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Brand List</label>
            <dataScope>brand_ids</dataScope>
        </settings>
    </field>
```

Field is displayed same as i need.

But now My question is i would like to display values of product attribute named **brand**

Brand is with Dropdown type product attribute and it contains values like Nike, Puma etc etc.

How can i achieve that ??

Any suggestions Please welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create functions that will return same array as **`toOptionArray`**.

> Vednor/Module/Block/File.php

```
public function toOptionArray() 
{

    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

    return $options;
}
```

- Than add below code in your ui_component file.

  ```
  <field name="brands_ids" formElement="multiselect">
      <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
          </item>
      </argument>
      <settings>
          <validation>
              <rule name="validate-brands" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
          </validation>
          <dataType>varchar</dataType>
          <label translate="true">Brand List</label>
          <dataScope>brands_ids</dataScope>
      </settings>
      <formElements>
          <multiselect>
              <settings>
                  <options class="Vendor\Module\Block\File"/>
              </settings>
          </multiselect>
      </formElements>
  </field>
  ```

Hope it will work !!